# How to load XML file with its comments using PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-scraping, simplexml

I'm trying to load an XML file using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://xxxxx/xxxxx.xml');
```

And XML file has some comments you can see in the pic below, which I'd like to use the data in the comments while creating my table:

[image: Original XML File Comments]

But when I tried to var_dump the data I see ["comments"] as:

```
["comment"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) {
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) {
    }
  }
```

Question is how could I retrieve the content of comments so I can use the lang names given in them?

Comment: Why on earth would you encode useful information as _comments_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **file_get_contents** instead:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://xxxxx/xxxxx.xml');
```

If you need xml to load into object then I think you have to use **DOMDocument()**:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('https://xxxxx/xxxxx.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$comment = $xpath->evaluate('string(//channel/item[1]/comment())');
echo $comment;
```

> var_dump($xml); // showing comments

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've solved it with a similar query like:
```/territory/languagePopulation/following::comment()[1]```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use DOMDocument as SimpleXML isn't good for comments.  You can use XPath to find the comment your after (use `normalize-space()` to remove spaces around the text) and `following-sibling` to return the following node.  The last line just outputs the element it's found, you will need to process it as required (use `[0]` as `query` will return a list of nodes and you just want the first one).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$lang = "Finland";
$langPop = $xp->query("//comment()[normalize-space(.)='$lang']/following-sibling::*[1]");

echo $doc->saveXML($langPop[0]);
```

With some sample data...

```
<base>
    <!-- Finland -->
    <languagePopulation>Finland data
    </languagePopulation>
    <!-- England -->
    <languagePopulation>England data
    </languagePopulation>
</base>
```

will give

```
<languagePopulation>Finland data
    </languagePopulation>
```